# what's the probability of hitting the starting point

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Suppose the dynamics of X follows:
$$dX_t = \mu(X_t)dt + \sigma(X_t)dZ_t$$
Where $Z_t$ is the standard Brownian motion. $\sigma(X)>0$ everywhere, and $\mu(1)>0$.

Starting from $X_0 = 1$, what would be the probability of $X_t$ hitting 1 again before time t? How should I calculate that? If I write it as a PDE for $P(X,t-\tau)$, where $P(X,t-\tau)$ denotes at time $\tau<t$, $X_t = X$, I will have the boundary condition that $P(1,t-\tau) = 1$ for any $\tau$.

Does it mean the probability always equal to $1$ for any $t>0$?

Comment: for such general setting you could take a look at Karatzas-Shreve in the Feller-test section.